# Memory usage in hazard pointer queue application

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, memory

I have recently testing queue with hazard pointer application as below :

https://github.com/chergert/dukes_of_hazard

I have noticed that RES raise quite fast in my own test ap ,

***MEMORY-ERROR***: [30770]: GSlice: failed to allocate 120 bytes (alignment: 128): Cannot allocate memory

happened in the end , the ap has 5 threads to enqueue , 5 threads to dequeue and then 
send to 5 socket server each thread , like following :

```
#include "lf-queue.h"

typedef struct People_
{
    int age ;
    char name[16] ;
    double income ;
} People ;

#define NUM 20000000

LfQueue *q ;
int    GlbCnt,GlbRow ;
int iConn[5] ;

int main()
{
    q = lf_queue_new();
    g_thread_init(NULL);

    if(DoConnect() != 1)
    {
        printf("Error in connect server .exe , port=5566,5567,5568,5569,5570 ! \n") ;
        exit(0) ;
    }

    pthread_t tid1[5],tid2[5];
    int icnt1[5] = {0,1,2,3,4} ;
    int icnt2[5] = {0,1,2,3,4} ;
    void    *func1(void *);
    void    *func2(void *);
    for(int idx=0;idx<5;idx++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid1[idx], NULL, &func1 , (void *) icnt1[idx] );
        pthread_create(&tid2[idx], NULL, &func2 , (void *) icnt2[idx] );
    }
    while(1){
        printf("Done(%d)\n",GlbCnt) ;
        sleep(1) ;
    }
} //main

void    *func1(void * inum)
{
    int ithread = (long)(int) inum ;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    People* p ;

    while(1){
        for(int idx=0;idx<NUM;idx++){
            usleep(1) ;
            p = (People *) malloc( sizeof(People) ) ;
            p->age = __sync_add_and_fetch(&GlbRow,1)   ;
            sprintf(p->name,"%s%08d","NAME",p->age ) ;
            p->income = p->age * 1.0 ;

            lf_queue_enqueue(q,p) ;
        }
        break ;
    } //while
}

void    *func2(void * inum)
{
    int ithread = (long)(int) inum ;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    People* p ;

    while(1){
        usleep(1) ;
        p = (People *) lf_queue_dequeue(q) ;;
        if(p){
            char line[128]={0} ;
            sprintf(line,"%010d|%s|%010.0f|",p->age,p->name,p->income) ;

            if (send(iConn[ithread],line,35,MSG_NOSIGNAL)<0){
                printf("send error \n");
                exit( 0 ) ;
            }
            __sync_add_and_fetch(&GlbCnt,1) ;
            free(p) ;
        }
    } //while
}
```